# Should " beginning" be followed by "with"?

Tags: prepositions, participles, present-participles

In unit 80 of 'Advanced Grammar in Use', it says

> In formal English we can also introduce a reason in a clause **beginning** for, in that, or less commonly, inasmuch as.

Shouldn't there be a preposition after "beginning", like "a clause beginning **with** for, in that ..."?

Comment: You can use 'with' in that position, but it is not mandatory.

Comment: What are the exact words you want to introduce a clause with? It is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence would be clearer had the author included "with". It would also help to place "for", "in that", and "inasmuch as" in quotation marks to indicate that those terms are being [mentioned (not used)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) and to distinguish them from the surrounding text.

Nevertheless, this sentence isn't wrong as written. Here is a similar example:

> The way some people have performed "The Star Spangled Banner," you might wonder if the national anthem begins, "Oh Say, Can't You Sing?" (Buck Wolf, "[Oh Say, Can't You Sing: Celebs Who Tortured the National Anthem](https://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/WolfFiles/story?id=1941484)," ABC News website, 2 May 2006)

Here the author has inserted a comma but still hasn't included "with". However, the quotation marks help the reader to understand the structure without any trouble.